# ddms - emulator control disabled on real phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

I need to emulate phone calls, but in ddms Emulate Control tab is disabled(grey). I tried turn on by menu/view etc. Clicked on device doesn't help.
I tried connect by telnet (localhost 5554) connection refused.
I work on Android Studio installed on linux mint. My testing device is Motorola Moto G with android 5.1 - debbug mode is ON.
On emulated device (Nexus) works OK - Emulate Control tab is ON.
Is there some trick to turn on this tab on hardware device connected?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some trick to turn on this tab on hardware device connected?

No, because it is not an emulator. Emulator Control is for emulators, not hardware.

Comment: So, how can I test my app on device I need simulate incoming calls?

Comment: @kolo: Either use an emulator, do real calls, or test your code in some other fashion.